# How do I create a custom form and controller in Spring Roo?

Tags: forms, spring, controller, annotations, spring-roo

I've been looking into this all day now, and I can't say I've quite understood how to go about this.

So far I've created a Spring Roo project along with a bunch of entities. What I want to do is allow the user to retrieve data from the database through a form. This means I will need a form for user input along with a controller that will handle the request after the user clicks on the "submit" button and get the information from the database.

The examples I've seen so far on the internet haven't really helped. I would really appreciate it if someone could explain how I can complete this task. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
roo>help
roo>web mvc setup
roo>web mvc all --package ~.web
```

Comment: I'm talking about a custom form and controller, not the generated ones.

Comment: @touvlo2000: what prevents you from writing one?

Answer (score 0):

Once Roo has set up the scaffolding you can simply add a new controller class like the ones roo  generates and code it to do what ever you want. Roo will leave your custom controllers and jsp files alone.

You can create your form based on a tutorial like this one http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-handling-forms/
and then call a roo generated finder method on your domain object.
[Spring/roo custom finder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838420/spring-roo-custom-finder) may help with this.

Roo will not generate the form to front the finder method.

I believe that effectively using roo requires a solid understanding of spring.  I would take a Spring 3 mvc tutorial (if you have not yet) and look over the files generated by roo and look up anything it generated that you don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same experience and it turned out i had jumped on learning Roo and trying to get it  to work for all my custom requirements without even understanding Spring web MVC completely.

My suggestion is to go through the Spring web mvc documentation and tutorials, create a small mvc application from scratch and then come back to Roo. Roo is great but you need to write your own code for all customization. So all you need to do is write your own controller and view for specific requirement.

BTW, did you see if your requirement (get the information from the database) is covered by any of the available finders? If it is, you just need to push in the right finder using Roo and it should be available to all users.